# How do I use a variable in XSL 2.0 xsl:key match attribute?

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="dictFile" select="document('dictionary.xml')" />
<xsl:key name="lookupTable" match="$dictFile/dictionary/item" use="@name" />
<xsl:variable name="lookup1" select="key('lookupTable','lookupA')" />
<xsl:variable name="lookup2" select="key('lookupTable','lookupB')" />
```

This does not compile with Saxon 9.5 EE returning an error:

```
XTSE0340 XSLT Pattern syntax error at char 0 on line 55 in {$dictFile}:
A variable reference is not allowed in an XSLT pattern (except in a predicate)
```

Unfortunately, I need to keep those variables lookup1 and lookup2 defined as they are. I would like to change as little code here as possible. It is a very old and large codebase running on a custom enterprise XSL engine that supports these kinds of constructs .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way in standard XSLT 2.0 would be

```
<xsl:variable name="dictFile" select="document('dictionary.xml')" />

<xsl:key name="lookupTable" match="dictionary/item" use="@name" />

<xsl:variable name="lookup1" select="key('lookupTable','lookupA', $dictFile)" />
<xsl:variable name="lookup2" select="key('lookupTable','lookupB', $dictFile)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This exact scenario is discussed in the [XSLT 2.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#keys) and **two** solutions are offered (scroll down to the *Example: Using Keys to Reference other Documents* part).